# Acceptance/Integration testing using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

Is there anything like cucumber in asp.net mvc?

i.e. something that will actually hit the web page using a browser?

Is selenium the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [specflow](http://specflow.org) to write cucumber style given-when-then steps, some of which could be selenium rc calls, or watin(.net version of watir) calls if you prefer. This way you can keep the syntax for writing acceptance tests that you're used to, while picking which ever web testing framework works best for you.

Since it's web stuff, with a bit of tweaking, you're not limited to using .net tools to test your asp.net mvc site - a web testing framework doesn't care how the website was made, just as a web browser doesn't.

Comment: that's true, but I'm sure there will be issues with using models etc. cross platform.

Comment: You're correct there. It's likely that you will need to inject models into your views for testing, to ensure your web tests are deterministic, avoiding a lot of maintenance, and if you're using the same technology that's going to be easier. I was just thinking that if you had already invested the time in setting up one web testing technology, you wouldn't necessarily have to redo that work. in .net